# Exibir Form em um TableLayoutPanel C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Como faço para abrir um formulário denominado `frmOrcamentos` dentro de um `TableLayoutPanel` denominado `tlpPrincipal`.
Lembrando que o formulário `frmOcamentos` será aberto no `TableLayoutPanel` que se encontra dentro do formulário `frmPrincipal` após clicar no botão `btnOrcamentos`.

Comment: coloca seu código...

Comment: Não tenho código ainda pois nem sei por onde começar.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei o que eu desejava fazer.
Código:

```
public partial class frmPrincipal : Form
{
    private Form _objForm; // Variável classe form

    public frmPrincipal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void tsbVendas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _objForm?.Close(); // Verifica se a variável _objForm já está ocupada, se estiver ele fecha

        _objForm = new frmVendas
        {
            TopLevel = false, // Desconsidera hierarquia das classes para não gerar erro
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None, // Remove a borda do formulário
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill // Expande formulário em todo o Panel
        };

        pnlPrincipal.Controls.Add(_objForm); // Adiciona formulário ao Panel
        _objForm.Show(); // Abre o formulário
    }
}
```